# Is "working with women that we grew up watching their body of work" grammatical?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> The fact that we were gonna be working with women **that** we grew up watching their body of work is just... incredible.  (Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fNHjc7hVIA [0:22])

The second 'that' sounds weird to me. Is this sentence grammatically correct? If not, how should it be changed?

Comment: You have a "gonna" in there and you are worried about the grammaticality of "_that_"?

Comment: I detect a hint of sarcasm.

Comment: no sarcasm. you made me thinking a lot. really helped

Comment: The whole *sentence* sounds weird. Exactly what is it trying to say?

Comment: The issue is the "resumptive pronoun" *their* in the relative clause. It refers to the same thing as "women." This is not grammatical in English: you can't have a pronoun in a relative clause that refers to the noun phrase that is being modified by the relative clause. (For example, we say "the women I saw," not "The women I saw **them**"--the second would be ungrammatical.)

Comment: One solution is to use the possessive relative pronoun *whose* and pied piping: "The fact that we were gonna be working with women whose body of work we grew up watching is just... incredible." This is grammatical, I think, but it doesn't sound great to me.

Comment: For more information on resumptive pronouns and relative clauses, see the following posts: [Interesting/weird syntax](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/330892), [“Give him a box that everyone knows what it contains.”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/173696)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fNHjc7hVIA [0:22]    thank you !! anyway

Comment: ok i got it I really appreciate your answer thank you~~

Comment: "Body of work" sounds odd.  It implies a collection, and growing up watching it implies that you stared at the same stuff your entire childhood.  It might be better to just refer to their work, or watching their work develop.

Answer (score 3):

The youtube link was extremely helpful.  When people are being interviewed, they don't have a chance to plan out their sentences very well, and grammar problems can arise.  It can happen to (almost) anyone.  If you punctuate her sentence like this, it's easier to understand:

> The fact that we were gonna be working with women that -- we grew up watching their body of work -- is just incredible.

Comment: yes, that makes some more sense now, nice suggestion, it also needs a 'with' after 'grew up' I would say. "The fact that we were gonna be working with women that -- we grew up with, watching their body of work -- is just incredible."

Comment: @Gary - Sorry if I wasn't clear.  I was trying to explain that the person who was interviewed *didn't* plan out her sentence well.  My impression was that this individual is a successful Hollywood actor -- probably not chosen for her ability to do good grammatical planning when being interviewed.